# Prove that 0 is a critical point of $x^TAx$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that 0 is a critical point of $f: R^n \to R$ when $f(x) = x^TAx$ and $A$ is a nonsingular, $n\times n$ matrix.

If I am understanding this correctly, $x$ would just be the zero matrix at $f(0)$, and anything times the zero matrix is just $0$. And since a critical point is any point at with $f = 0$, $0$ is a critical point of $f$.

That seems to be the entire proof. Am I missing something?

Comment: Critical value, right? so what's $\nabla f?$

Comment: As the others have been getting at, you misinterpreted the definition of a critical point: it's not when $f=0$, but rather when $\nabla f=(0,0,\dots, 0)$.

Answer (score 3):

You have $|f(x)-f(0) - 0 x| = |f(x)| \le \|A\| \|x\|^2$. It follows that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and
$Df(0) = 0$.

**Aside**: A function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative $G$ **iff** for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $\|h\| < \delta$ then 
$\|f(x+h)-f(x) - Gh \| \le \epsilon \|h\|$.

In the above, we can take $\delta = {\epsilon \over \|A\|}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you got $|f(x)-f(0) - 0 x| = |f(x)|$

Comment: @WalterSobchack: Well, $f(0) = 0$, and $0x=0$, this part is just show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition, for example.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Also, how does proving that $|f(x)| \le \|A\| \|x\|^2$ prove that f is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: @WalterSobchack: I added some text, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of the function:   Here $x$ is viewed is viewed as column vector $(n \times 1)$, so $x^T$ is a row vector $(1 \times n).$    Then $Ax$ is also $n \times 1,$ and thus $x^T (Ax)$ is a scalar.  The comment above is correct you need to find the gradient of $f$ (partial derivatives).  If you have little or no experience differentiating functions of this nature,  I suggest you look at the expansion of $f$ below: 
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) =\sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{j=1}^n  A_{ij} x_i x_j 
$$

Also, Is $A$ symmetric?  If not, with the assumptions you stated, there may be additional (infinitely many!) critical points.